# Placing paragraphs within text fields or labels

Tags: cocoa, newline, touch

How do I place a small paragraph within a text field or label?  Do I use code for the new line?  I'm using Interface Builder with Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must mean more than one paragraph, because a single paragraph doesn't need a new line.  Just copy it out of a text editor and paste it in.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using an Text View (NSTextView/UITextView) instead of a text field or a label.